# How can I remove water stains from a wooden counter top?

Tags: wood, water-damage, countertops

There is a portion of wood next to the sink that must not be treated properly or over time the treatment has worn down due to water damage.

What is the best way to treat / deal with this? I was thinking to sand down the affected area and then find a sealant as the wood is still sound other than the mold on the top layer.

Any tips would be great!

[image]

Comment: That's not "rotting". It's just water damage.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I remove blackened water stains from a hardwood floor?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/16640/is-there-a-way-to-remove-blackened-water-stain-from-hardwood-floor)

Comment: That's probably not mold, either. Looks like a dish drying rack or something similar normally sits at the edge and has trapped water under it allowing it to seep into the wood. Once you've refinished, don't put it back or this will happen again.